# Calculated column in Power BI that repeats different sums based on conditions in 2 other columns

Tags: powerbi, formula, dax, powerquery, calculated-columns

I need a calculated column based on conditions in two columns (Business Unit Number in both tables and L1/Account Categories in 1st table and the second table) which sum and then repeat for several rows before the conditions change and a new sum is repeated for several rows and so on.  The L1/Account Categories columns have different names because it's the raw data.

For example, any time ASSETS and 111 appear in the same row, I would want to use those as conditions and with the sum of all of the other matching rows in a new column and the sum would repeat each time both conditions appeared in the same row.  Any time P/L and 111 appear in the same row, that would be a sum of all other P/L and 111 appearances in the dataset (about 1000 rows overall)... and so on.

I've tried formulas with DAX using FILTER, SUMX, nested IF statements and also tried the Power Query language among other attempts.  Maybe I have to create one or more than one new table?  If you need to take a look at a few of my attempts, just let me know.

The top image is how I imagine the output will look in the power query editor and the bottom image is a sample of the source data.

[image: Look something like this]

[image]

This last pic is from Tableau - I need to make a table in Power BI which essentially a duplicate of this image.  The last 2 columns are pulling from different tables.

[image: Tableau screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be very simple to achieve with relationships and measures - no need for calculated columns or power query merges. You need to build a relationship between these two tables. In fact, I would introduce a third table in your model for Business unit.

The limitation of Power BI model relationships is that they can only be based on a single column. So to build a relationship between these two tables you would have to add a calculated column in both of them that would contain both a BU and the financial statement line, for instance: `JoinCol = CONCATENATE([Business_Unit_Number], [L1])`. Then you could create a relationship and do what you want.

The better (one that I would recommend) approach would be to separate Business Unit into a separate table and have relationships built like this:

[image]

Then all you have to do in your visual is drag Business unit name from the BU table, L1 from the FS Lines table and a measure to sum the amounts `Amount = SUM('Financial Data'[Rolled Up Detail])`.

Here is a working sample: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmqvMyRqhrBpgtUT5HKnZP1U3Gzc9w?e=en91dV

[image]